# Can't convert T-SQL INNER JOIN to LINQ-Entities query

Tags: c#, t-sql, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, inner-join

T-SQL:

```
declare @postlocations table (locationid int)
insert into @postlocations
select locationid
from dbo.PostLocations
where PostId = 162172

select t.*
from dbo.Themes t
inner join dbo.ThemeLocations tl on t.ThemeId = tl.ThemeId
inner join @postlocations pl on tl.LocationId = pl.locationid
```

LINQ-Entities i have so far:

```
var postLocations = e.SomePost.Locations; // pre-fetched, e.g materialized ICollection<Post>
var themes = (from t in db.Themes
             join q in postLocations on t.Locations.Select(l => l.LocationId) equals q.LocationId
             select t).ToList();
```

But the compiler is complaining on the `join` keyword about not being able to infer the type arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your T-SQL two separate queries to begin with? It looks like it should be a single query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - because the first one is actually an in memory collection. Same source data, but already pre-fetched.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can join a SQL table with an in-memory list of objects, even if those objects are originally from the database.

Convert the in-memory list of objects to a list of id's (integer), and use that in the join or in a Contains/sub-select. EF can translate the list of id's to parameters when generating the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your join is that you're implying a collection of `LocationId` (`t.Locations.Select(l => l.LocationId`) can equal a single `LocationId`. You're trying to join a Theme which has a collection of Locations onto a single Location.

You should be able to fix this by using `Contains`

```
var themes = (from t in db.Themes
             join q in postLocations 
             on t.Locations.Select(l => l.LocationId).Contains(q.LocationId)
             select t).ToList();
```

or if EF complains about passing a `postLocations` as a parameter, you can try

```
// I'd materialize this but you may not have to
var postLocationIds = postLocations.Select(p => p.LocationId).ToList();

var themes = db.Themes.Where(t => t.Locations.Any(l => 
                 postLocationIds.Contains(l.LocationId))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

how about this

```
 ///your sql query
select t.* from dbo.Themes t
 inner join dbo.ThemeLocations tl on t.ThemeId = tl.ThemeId
 inner join @postlocations pl on tl.LocationId = pl.locationid 

//linq query for that
from t in teams
join from tl in teamlocation on t.themid = tl.ThemeID
join from pl in postlocation on tl.temeid = pl.temeid
select t;
```

**Org**

Not sure but you can try out by using let keyword

```
var themes = (from t in db.Themes
              let location = t.Locations

            join q in postLocations on location.LocationId equals q.LocationId 
            select t).ToList();
```